# Regex to Match Urls in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby-on-rails-3, hyperlink

I have looked around but I haven't really found an answer that seals the deal 100% for my individual situation.

In my Ruby app, I have a user share system where members can post 'stuff'.  Well, sometimes members post links, and I have noticed as the site grows, more and more users are complaining about there not being clickable links.

How would I utilize regular expressions to match urls for links in posts.  Furthermore, how would I apply this in my Model?

Thanks for you help, out of all my questions, this is a real important one for me ha!

**EDIT**

I suppose my init post was too vague...

I am more trying to figure out HOW to IMPLEMENT the use of regular expressions into my model  instead of which regular expression to use.

The model is `class Share`.  And the member's post is rendered as `<%= share.content %>` with content being a column in my Share table as well as an accessible attribute...

Thanks.

Comment: What are we looking for? <a> tags? Markdown syntax? Or just find http(s) strings? A little help please.

Comment: http(s) strings, sorry!  Lke if someone posted http://asite.com it would link it.  Is it possible, even if they posted, www.asite.com? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

autolink will do it.  It's been extracted into it's own gem...

https://github.com/tenderlove/rails_autolink

Example usage:

```
auto_link("Go to http://www.rubyonrails.org and say hello to david@loudthinking.com")
# => "Go to <a href=\"http://www.rubyonrails.org\">http://www.rubyonrails.org</a> and
#     say hello to <a href=\"mailto:david@loudthinking.com\">david@loudthinking.com</a>"
```

Comment: I have seen autolink but I am unsure how it is actually meant to be applied as its synopsis is quite vague.

Comment: I do not mean to be frustrating, but that is just a copy out of the synopsis... which I said was quite vague.  This tells me nothing.  As in... where am I supposed to put this?  The member's post is rendered as <%= share.content %> so I have no clue where this "auto_link" tag goes. =/

Comment: `<%= auto_link(share.content) %>`

Comment: That was easy enough.  Thank you friend :)

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
^(([^:/?#]+):)?(//([^/?#]*))?([^?#]*)(\?([^#]*))?(#(.*))?
```

from the [IETF Specification on URLS](http://www.apps.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.html). It matches ALL URLS including "ftp://..." so you may need to tweak it somewhat.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to try and help, I really do appreciate it.  But my question was "How would I utilize regular expressions to match urls for links in posts. Furthermore, how would I apply this in my Model?"  I say 'utilize', for I do not know how to implement its use.  SOrry if I was vague.